# GET request to webpage returns string, but cannot use it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a google chrome extension, and when I make a get request to this web page `https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E27675&maxBedrooms=2&minBedrooms=2&sortType=6&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=`, I get the webpage HTML as a response which is what I want (the website I am requesting info from does not have an API and I cannot web scrape for reasons too long to explain here). This response comes in the form of a string. When I attempt to split this string at a certain point, `bis_skin_checked`, I am returned an array of length 1, meaning that there was no match and nothing has been split. But when I look at the string returned it has it included.

I have tried things like removing spaces and carriage returns but nothing seems to be working. This is my GET request code:

```
function getNewPage(url) {
    let returnedValue = fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        return text
    })

    return returnedValue
}
```

I then go on to resolve the promise which is `returnedValue`:

```
let newURL = getHousePrices(currentUrl) // Get Promise of new page as a string

newURL.then(function(value) { // Resolve promise and do stuff
    console.log(value.split('bis_skin_checked').length)
})
```

And then work with the string which looks like this: (I have attached an image as I cannot copy the text from the popup)

[Image Link To API Request return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuiTG.png)

Comment: _"I cannot web scrape"_... isn't that literally what you _are_ doing?

Comment: You didn't show us the code that's actually failing, which is the code that does a "split".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that's trying to use your function. You mentioned trying to split the string... where is that code

Comment: No idea who downvoted (votes are anonymous) but I was only attempting to educate. Programmatically fetching a web page and parsing the response is the very definition of [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Comment: @TimRoberts code has been edited to show this. The value returned by that is 1

Comment: I can't see that string you're looking for anywhere in the response (pulled it down myself). Can you show why you think it's present? The screenshot in your question is from an `alert()` but there isn't one in any of your code

Comment: FYI you're violating that site's [terms of use](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/this-site/terms-of-use.html)... _"5.3 You must not use or attempt to use any automated program (including, without limitation, any spider or other web crawler) to access our system or this Site. You must not use any scraping technology on the Site. Any such use or attempted use of an automated program shall be a misuse of our system and this Site. Obtaining access to any part of our system or this Site by means of any such automated programs is strictly unauthorised."_

Comment: So the response is being turned into a string through the GET I think as I am requesting it in the html/text format. When I do `typeof(newURL)` it tells me it is a string

Comment: @Phil (and your browser) is right.  The string `"bis_skin_checked"` is not present in the downloaded HTML.  In fact, the downloaded string has basically no HTML at all.  What you're looking for must be being created dynamically by Javascript code.

Comment: The string exists when I make the same request in postman though?

Comment: I'm a full time browser extension dev and I think I have a better solution. It depends though - what data are you trying to get specifically? Because you can add host permissions and mimic the fetch request that yields all the property data in background.js - I just tested that and it gave me all the properties given your set of params. Is that what you want? It would be a much more reliable solution. --- I can go into more detail and write out the code you would need. Just let me know what data you want to see.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the home values, given certain search parameters.

Scraping raw text is usually not the way to go. I took a look at the site and saw it uses uniform network requests that you can modify to capture the data you need directly instead of scraping the raw HTML.

I built a solution that allows you to dynamically pass whatever parameters you want to the `getHomes()` function. Passing nothing will use the default params that you can use as a baseline while you try to adjust the request for any additional modifications/use cases.

Install the below solution and run `getHomes()` from the service worker.

Here's a brief video I made explaining the solution: https://vimeo.com/772275354/07fd1025ed

```
--- manifest.JSON ---
{
    "name": "UK Housing - Stackoverflow",
    "description": "Example for how to make network requests and mimic them in background.js to avoid web scraping raw text",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.rightmove.co.uk/*"
    ]
}
```

```
--- background.js ---
async function getHomes(passedParams) {

    const newParams = passedParams ? passedParams : {}; // set to an empty object if no new params passed - avoid error in object.entries loop.

    // starts with default params for a working request, you can then pass params to override the defaults to test new requests.
    var params = {
        "locationIdentifier": "REGION%5E27675",
        "maxBedrooms": "2",
        "minBedrooms": "1",
        "numberOfPropertiesPerPage": "25",
        "radius": "0.0",
        "sortType": "6",
        "index": "0",
        "viewType": "LIST",
        "channel": "BUY",
        "areaSizeUnit": "sqft",
        "currencyCode": "GBP",
        "isFetching": "false"
    }

    Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        // we iterate through each key in our default params to check if we passed a new value for that key.
        // we then set the params object to the new value if we did.
        if (newParams[key]) params[key] = newParams[key];
    });

    const rightMoveAPISearch = `https://www.rightmove.co.uk/api/_search?
        locationIdentifier=${params['locationIdentifier']}
        &maxBedrooms=${params['maxBedrooms']}
        &minBedrooms=${params['minBedrooms']}
        &numberOfPropertiesPerPage=${params['numberOfPropertiesPerPage']}
        &radius=${params['radius']}
        &sortType=${params['sortType']}
        &index=${params['index']}
        &viewType=${params['viewType']}
        &channel=${params['channel']}
        &areaSizeUnit=${params['areaSizeUnit']}
        &currencyCode=${params['currencyCode']}
        &isFetching=${params['isFetching']}
    `.replace(/\s/g, ''); // removes the whitespaces we added to make it look nicer / easier to adjust.

    const data = await
        fetch(rightMoveAPISearch, {
            "method": "GET",
        })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(res => { return res })
    
    if (data.resultCount) {
        console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'Request successful! Result count: ', parseInt(data.resultCount));
        console.log('All data: ', data);
        console.log('Properties: ', data.properties);
    }
    else console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', `Issue with the request:`, data)

    return data

}
```

Hope this is helpful. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. You are an absolute legend!!!!